# JavaFX 8 monopoly

Tags: javafx-8

What would be the best approach to draw a monopoly gameboard with javafx, I need to be able to put houses on te properties and show the pawns on the right place of the board when players move. The squares do not have to be clickable.

Comment: I'd probably start with a `GridPane` with `StackPane`s in each element of the grid representing a square on the board. Then you can add content to the stack panes as needed.

Comment: The easiest way to draw the board is just to load [the whole thing](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81oC5pYhh2L._SL1500_.jpg) up in a single ImageView.  You can then put it in a StackPane to have a Pane layered on top of the ImageView into which dynamic elements are placed.  But really there are numerous ways to accomplish this task, probably you need to make your own decision as to what is write (e.g. a monolithic background image or everything composed of dymanically drawn regions on the board).